# "Tune commodum ducis meæ adhuc confabulationi vacare"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin

I am having some trouble understanding the first line of Abraham (a medieval play by Hrotsvitha).

> Tune, frater et coeremita Ephrem, commodum ducis meæ adhuc confabulationi vacare, an quoad usque divinas expleas laudes, me vis præstolari?

Here what I got so far:

> [My] brother and fellow-hermit Ephrem, now [?] for a conversation, or do you want that I wait until you have finished your prayers?

But I can't make sense of "Tune commodum ducis meæ adhuc confabulationi vacare", I guess it means something like "can you give me some time to converse right now" but I am confused with the use of both adhhuc and commodum and by the ducis/vacare.

Answer (score 7):

Duco here has the meaning of “consider” or “esteem” (something as something). It is governing two accusatives, vacare and commodum. Commodum is the predicate accusative: ducis vacare [esse] commodum. “Do you consider making time [to be] convenient”

Vaco with the dative is “to have/make time for [dative]”. Vacare meae confabulationi = making time for my discourse

Adhuc here seems to mean something like “now (already, as opposed to later”, but I’m not familiar with that use of it.